# Oozie: kill a job after a timeout

Tags: apache-spark, timeout, oozie

Sorry but can't find he configuration point a need. I schedule spark application, sometimes they may not succeed after 1 hour, in this case I want to automatically kill this task (because I am sure it will never succeed, and another scheduling may start).

I found a timeout configuration, but as I understand it, this is used to delay the start of a workflow.

So is there a kind of living' timeout ?

Comment: Why don't schedule with oozie a shell script that runs every hour for example checks long running applications in YARN and then kills them?

Answer (score 0):

Oozie cannot kill a workflow that it triggered. However you can ensure that a single workflow is running at same time by setting Concurrency = 1 in the Coordinator.
Also you can have a second Oozie workflow monitoring the status of the Spark job.

Anyawy, you should investigate the root cause of Spark job not successful or being blocked.